# Concatenation in SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I'm trying to use the concat function in SQL Server 2014. It keeps giving me this error though and I'm curious why and how to get around it? MY code is below. Thank you!

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 17 'concat' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name.

```
Select concat([Column 2], [Column 3]) 
    FROM [eCommerce1].[dbo].[All march june Data]
    GO
```

Comment: and what would "this error" message be?

Comment: @Lamak Sorry forgot to include it. It is there now

Comment: and what's the compatibility level of the `eCommerce1` database?

Comment: What is `select @@version` too?

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2014 like you say in your question, or is this SQL Server Management Studio 2014 like you say in your title? Using SSMS 2014 to connect to an older version of SQL Server doesn't make new functions available.

Comment: @MartinSmith that explains it. The @@version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3)

Comment: @hvd That makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, you can't use features in a newer version of SQL Server on older versions of the product, regardless of what SSMS version you are using. In the case of concatenation, this should do just as well in your case, using older syntax from SQL Server 2000 (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862(v=sql.80).aspx).

```
SELECT [Column 2] + [Column 3]
FROM [eCommerce1].[dbo].[All march june Data]
GO
```

Comment: Thank you! so quick question how would I insert that new column into my table,

Comment: If it's in the same table then `UPDATE [table] SET [concatenated_column] = [Column 2] + [Column 3]` will do it. If you're inserting into a new table then it would be `INSERT INTO [new_table] ([concatenated_column]) SELECT [Column 2] + [Column 3] FROM [old_table]`.